# Keyboard key's pressed a lot of times

Tags: python, keyboard

I want to create program that check if a is pressed. But for a lot of times, not only one time. I tried using for loop and function but I failed.

```
import keyboard

def lagun():
    while True:
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
                print('you pressed a')
                break
        except:
            break
```

Can anyone could tell me how to modify this code to check is a is pressed a lot of times?

Comment: You can use a counter to count the time the key is pressed in a specific period of time

Comment: in order to count different presses you need to also detect the the key is released, so you can count the next press. make a two state machine, where in order to count a new press you first need to detect that the key has been released. You can use pyinput, take a look at https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-detect-keypress/ to get a template with a `on_press`and `on_release` events

Comment: Wow, it worked! I don't know why but that's what I wanted. Than you  Sembei Norimaki!